# Devexpress LinqServerModeDataSource vs LinqDataSource

Tags: devexpress, linqdatasource

I need to access the returned results of a LinqServerModeDataSource. When using the normal Linqdatasource you can access this information in the "Selected" event e.Result,  but the devexpress object does not have this event.
Now that I think about it there are no "ed" events "Updated", "Inserted" only "ing" events on the devexpress data source.

Any help would be great
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered getting the data through the ASPxGridView once the data is returned?

Or you can use the Microsoft LinqDataSource with the ASPxGridView.